# Drop down menu stops working for smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I'm working on creating a drop down menu, but I've noticed that is only works under certain circumstances.
When isolated by itself, the menu works perfectly:

```
<nav class = "navigation">
                    <div class="button-wrapper">
                        <button>
                            <p>Resume</p>               
                        </button>
                        <div class="hidden">
                            <div class="menu-option">
                                <p>Download<p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-option">
                                <p>
                                    <a href ="http://www.mywebsite.com/resume.html">
                                        View Online
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-wrapper">
                        <button>
                            <p>3D Modeling</p>              
                        </button>
                        <div class="hidden">
                            <div class="menu-option">
                                <p>Portfolio(PDF)<p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-option">
                                <p>Projects</p>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-wrapper">
                        <button>
                            <p>Programming</p>              
                        </button>
                        <div class="hidden">
                            <div class="menu-option">
                                <p>Projects<p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-option">
                                <p>Code Bits</p>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-wrapper">
                        <button>
                            <p>Other</p>                
                        </button>
                        <div class="hidden">
                            <div class="menu-option">
                                <p>NA<p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-wrapper">
                        <button>
                            <p>Contact</p>              
                        </button>
                    </div>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.button-wrapper {
    color: black;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
    width: inherit
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.hidden p {
    width: inherit;
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.menu-option:hover p {
    background: #888;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

button {
    float: right;
        width: auto;
    height: 40px;
        padding: 10px 30px;

}

div {
    background: #555;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

body, div, nav, footer {
    background: #555;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

header div h1 {
    color: white;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 11px;
        height: 100px;
}

header, .content, footer {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
}

.button-wrapper:hover .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

p {
    margin: 0px;    
}

nav {
    margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
    display: flex;
    background: none;
}
```

When apart of the entire webpage it works if the screen is large enough, but once the screen width gets small enough (around 900px), the menu disappears when you try to mouse over the last option:

Any ideas what is keeping the menu from functioning properly?

Comment: issue with .hidden p this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a positioning issue created by the fact that the `button`s are floated, but the dropdown isn't `clear`ed. To fix it, just add `clear: both;` and `position: relative;` to your `.hidden` panel elements.

Example:

```
.hidden {
    clear: both; // Add this line
    position: relative; // And this line
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
    width: inherit
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was thinking it was something subtle that I'd missed.