# Dropdown list (language selector) is not working when screen is narrow

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu

I'm constructing a website on the base of [TheNest HTML template](https://themeforest.net/item/nest-real-estate-html-template/20191775) and am using a dropdown language selector from [MDB, Material Design Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/dropdown-language-selector/). The website has adaptive design, which means that it looks differently on narrow screens. The language selector is situated on the main menu (which is under top menu on the picture 1).
[image: On the wide screen everything looks good] The list opens at mouse hover over it.

When I'm narrowing the screen, in order to simulate the site appearance on the phone or tablet, the top menu disappears, the main menu goes to the top and gets black. At this, the dropdown language selector stops working (picture 2). It doesn't open on hover anymore. Something prevents it from opening.
[image: On the narrow screen selector is not working]

Can anyone help me to solve it? I can give a link to the development server, if needed.

Comment: Is it possible to replicate your issue with minimal replicable example?

Comment: I'm trying to debug the issue. Now I can say that the issue doesn't depend on the place where selector is situated. I copied it to the other place of the page. It works until the window width is below ~992px, then stops working. I think, the problem is in one of CSS styles, which control behaviour of the page at different screen width, such as @media (max-width: 992px). This is all by the moment. Looking further...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my dropdown list didn't work, was that at smaller screens the elements have different default positioning: float? flex? don't know exactly. If anyone knows, please specify in comments. First hint I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725516/drop-down-menu-stops-working-for-smaller-screens), but the solution is from some other source.

The solution was to explicitly specify property display:block to all popping elements on mouse hover. Here is a fragment of project.css file:

```
@media (min-width: 180px){
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
         ...
         display:block;    
    }
    .dropdown .dropdown-item:hover > .dropdown-menu {
         display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
         display: block;
    }
}
```

Now the dropdown list works well!